# Trouble with Joins and Counts in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am confused on this MySQL select query, I get the correct information back except the `COUNT(messages)` and `COUNT(project_ideas)` are coming back twice as many.

```
SELECT  
    create_project.title, 
    image1, 
    create_project.description, 
    create_project.date, 
    create_project.active, 
    create_project.completed, 
    create_project.project_id, 
    categories.name,
    messages.receiver_read, 
    project_ideas.project_id,
    COUNT(messages.ideas_id) AS num_of_messages,
    COUNT(project_ideas.ideas_id) AS num_of_ideas
FROM 
    create_project
    LEFT JOIN project_ideas ON create_project.project_id = project_ideas.project_id
    LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.project_id = create_project.project_id
    JOIN categories ON create_project.category = categories.category_id 
WHERE 
    create_project.user_id = {$_SESSION['user']['user_id']} 
    AND create_project.active = 1 
    AND create_project.completed = 1
GROUP BY project_ideas.project_id
ORDER BY create_project.date ASC
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: If you leave out the `GROUP BY`, you can see why. You best option is `COUNT(DISTINCT messaged.some_uniqe_column_of_messages)`, probably the primary key...

Comment: I also see an SQL injection vulnerability. Use prepared statements with PDO instead of putting the values of variables directly into the SQL. Even if you think that session variable is clean, you're still rolling the dice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is more than one row in your `create_project` table that matches to a single row in your `messages` table, then the row in `messages` will show up once for each matching row in `create_project`. Additionally, since you have many joins, you have many places for duplicate rows to show up. If a project belongs to more than one category, for example, your join against `categories` will result in every row from the other tables being duplicated for each category that a project belongs to. I'd wager this is actually the source of your error. And what makes it so insidious is that the `GROUP BY` hides the duplication everywhere except in functions that do counting and summing.

@Wrikken's comment is correct and useful. If you remove the `GROUP BY`, you'll see every row included in the count. There you should see that rows from the `messages` table are repeated. As @Wrikken also said, you can mitigate this by using `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`. I would try, however, to make sure your joins are correct or that your table data is correct, before papering over the problem with a `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`. That is to say, make sure that `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` really makes logical sense in terms of the data you are looking for.

Unrelated to your action question, I had to point out something that I see (and have done myself before I knew better). Although MySQL lets you include columns in your select list that are not in a `GROUP BY` or an aggregate function (e.g., `COUNT()`), it's bad practice to do so. The results are technically undefined (see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html). I think MySQL is wrong for doing this, but it's not my call. Other database systems would flag this as an error.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
COUNT(messages.ideas_id) OVER(PARTITION BY  messages.project_id)  AS num_of_messages,
COUNT(project_ideas.ideas_id) OVER(PARTITION BY  project_ideas.project_id) AS num_of_ideas
```

Comment: Read the tags and the title. MySQL does not have window functions.

Comment: I got burned on MySQL second time today.  Sorry about that.